# Does "burning" water fall under the Av Melachah of "bishul" on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, halacha-theory, melacha-creative-work, cooking-bishul

If water that falls onto a hot plate on Shabbos immediately "burns" up and evaporates, does this fall under the Av Melachah of bishul? (The pracitical application of this I want to leave aside. Especially since there are points involved of malacha shaino tzricha l'gufu, davar shaino miscavain, etc.) My question in particular is if this is considered to be a "maseh bishul" or do we look at the water being burnt up and evaporated in a different way in terms of Meleches Shabbos.

Comment: kind of parallel http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18527/759

Comment: @DoubleAA The Chasam Sofer brought there is quite relevant I think to this question.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question to ask about a Melachah, rather than an Issur, especially if you are assuming we should set aside whether it has practical application.

Comment: Please let me know if this edit works for you.

Answer (score 3):

See :שבת דף עד where we learn about something similar:

```
האי מאן דשדא סיכתא לאתונא חייב משום מבשל
```

Somebody who throws a wooden peg into an oven has trangressed Bishul, since the moisture in the peg gets cooked away. He is חייב even though his intention was to fortify the peg, and not to dry it out.