# Why isn't burning the limbs considered the melacha of cooking?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi

In [Yevamos 33b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.33b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the *gemarra* is trying to figure out what part of the Temple service would constitute a Shabbos violation if a non-Kohen were to do it. The *gemarra* suggests throwing the animal limbs on the altar (הקטרה), but rejects that because the *gemarra* is discussing Rabbi Yossi, who holds that burning a fire on Shabbos (הבערה) isn't a bona fide Shabbos violation that results in *kares*/an obligation for an offering. Rather, it's simply a prohibition worthy of lashes. The *gemarra* therefore suggests something else.

I was very bothered that why isn't הקטרה considered the Shabbos prohibition of cooking? The meat gets cooked in the altar fire. I then noticed that Rabbi Akiva Eiger there says [Yerushalmi Shabbos 2:5](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=602433&pagenum=46) teaches a dispute in this. Rabbi Yehudah says that הקטרה is the prohibition of burning a fire on Shabbos, and Rabbi Yossi holds הקטרה is the prohibition of cooking. They seem to be arguing if something I want to get cooked but not eat is the violation of cooking on Shabbos, but I could be misunderstanding.

Why didn't the *Bavli gemarra* say this as well? Subsequently I found that the [Nishmas Adam 20:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Nishmat_Adam%2C_Shabbat_and_Festivals.20.2?lang=bi) says that in a dispute Rabbi Yehudah and Rabbi Yossi, we go with Rabbi Yossi. The conclusion of the Yerushalmi would then be that הקטרה is cooking. However, he infers from the *gemarra* in Yevamos that we started with that the *Bavli* disagrees, even according to Rabbi Yehudah (?).

What's the dispute between the *Bavli* and the *Yerushalmi*?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18527/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21906/759

Comment: If it's the same R' Yossi, then it's a contradiction already?

Comment: Maybe according to the Yerushalmi *haktarah* is *bishul* because this is the way you "cook" the meat for Hashem?

Comment: Maybe a Melacha She'ayna Zricha L'Gufo? no point in the "cooking", we just need to burn it and/or cause a Rei'ach Nichoach.

Comment: It seems like a dispute as to what R' Yossi actually held.