# Mushrooms from the carcass of a non-kosher animal

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, animals

Some [Mushrooms](https://www.quora.com/Do-mushrooms-grow-on-dead-animals) can grow from decomposing animals.

Would there be any (kashrus) problems with having mushrooms that grow from the carcasses of non-kosher animals?

Comment: A quite much related issue: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38785/15256

Comment: Are you referring specifically to mushrooms that grow on dead, decaying animals? In such a case, you would probably be dealing with an issue of whether a dog would eat the rotting decaying carcass. If not, it would fall out of the definition of food generally. But mushrooms such as cordyceps actually start their growth on living insects. The insect dies through the spore infection and the mature mushroom sprouts out of the head of the ultimately dead insect. FYI, cordyceps are highly prized medicinally.

Comment: Mushrooms are special in that they derive their nourishment from humidity in the air, not the ground, which is why their blessing is *sheakol*. Is this why you ask specifically about mushrooms? Would likely make them easier to eat in respect to your question

Comment: @mbloch The fact that mushrooms grow from humidity is partially why I asked about mushrooms. My question can also be applied to other foods that are grown/produced directly from non-kosher animals. The essence of my question takes into account both of these ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard from one of the Star- K Rabbis. In the name of Rav Heineman that it depends on whether all its nutrients are from the dead animal. The Cordyceps mushroom which in nature is complelty dependent on the catappilar it takes over is not kosher because *kol hayotzim meihatami tamei*. Though at the time only cordyceps mushroom was described as not kosher so I am not sure if there is any other mushroom it applies to.

Comment: Interesting idea, you must be referring to YD 60:1 but the caterpillars aren't assur behanaah.