# Does handling dinosaur bones make one Tamei?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

[This story](http://www.cnn.com/2013/10/03/tech/canada-large-dinosaur-fossil-found/index.html?hpt=hp_t2) about a pipeline digger cracking through a fossilized dinosaur tail made me wonder: Does handling dinosaur bones make one Tamei?

[Lizards](http://taaruvos.blogspot.com/2005/11/sheretz-list.html) are considered Sheratzim, but by and large Sheratzim are "creepy crawling things", so maybe only smaller dinosaurs, especially small, four-legged dinosaurs fit the description.  [Some claim](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/jewsevolution.html) that dinosaurs were part of an earlier creation that was later destroyed; if so, would small, Sheretz-like dinosaurs even count?

Comment: This would seem to depend on whether or not fossils are still bones al pi halacha.

Comment: @yoel, apropos your comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16769/5

Comment: I don't know how you know what species are sheratzim.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I linked to a post that gave a general list.

Comment: *I don't know how anyone could know what species are sheratzim

Comment: My theory is dinosaurs WERE the serpent before the curse cut its limbs off. Snakes do not count as one of the eight sheratzim therefore they would not give tumah ab Initio.

Answer (score 5):

once an animal carcass has dried it is no longer tamei. see mishna 1 in keilim (bartenura)